# Update Partial Data In Firestore Document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've built a real-time web editor similar to the one at firepad.io for my purposes, in a web-app.

I'm using firestore backend, utilizing it's real-time sync capabilities (Great!)

At this time, I store the content of my text editor as a document, the problem is that every time the content changes, I've to make a WRITE for the entire document in the firestore. I think it's a waste of network bandwidth, plus it's probably costly as well (I haven't done the cost evaluation yet).

Is there a way to make partial updates to a document in firestore?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can [update individual fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data), each value being written entirely.  That's as small of a write you can make.  But a document write of any size is still billed as 1 write operation.